# copiar imagen .jpg con streams y arrayList<Integer>

Tags: java, stream

Estoy intentando copiar una imagen con el siguiente código pero el archivo .jpg que me genera no puedo verlo. Seguramente no se está volcando la información correctamente. Creo que el problema está en el método crearFoto pero no sé por qué no funciona.

```
    private static ArrayList<Integer> bytesFoto = new ArrayList <Integer>();
public static void main (String args []) {
    leerFoto(bytesFoto);
    //System.out.println(bytesFoto.size());
    crearFoto(bytesFoto);
}
public static void crearFoto(ArrayList<Integer> datosFichero) { 
    File fotoNueva = new File("manejo_streams/copia_java_glaciar.jpg");
    ObjectOutputStream ficheroNuevo = null;
    try {
        ficheroNuevo = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fotoNueva));     
        for(int i =0; i<bytesFoto.size();i++) {
            int byteFoto = datosFichero.get(i);
            ficheroNuevo.writeInt(byteFoto);
        }
        ficheroNuevo.close();           
    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Ha habido algún error en la escritura.");
    }   
}
public static void leerFoto(ArrayList<Integer> bytesFoto) { 
    int contador =0;        
    try {
        FileInputStream archivo_lectura = new FileInputStream("manejo_streams/glaciar.jpg");        
        boolean final_ar=false;     
        while(!final_ar) {          
            int byte_entrada=archivo_lectura.read();
            //System.out.println(byte_entrada);             
            if(byte_entrada !=-1) { 
                bytesFoto.add(byte_entrada); //Almacena en ArrayList
            } else {
                final_ar=true;
            }
        }
        archivo_lectura.close();
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("No se ha encontrado el archivo.");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("La lectura del archivo ha sido incorrecta.");
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya he encontrado cómo solucionarlo. Estaba utilizando la clase `ObjectOutputStream` en vez de `FileOutputStream` en el método `crearFoto`